# Angular Nested Tree как при загрузке открыть нужную ветку?

Tags: angular

Есть стандартный проект Angular Nested Tree https://stackblitz.com/angular/omabppadxox?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts. Как сделать, чтобы при загрузки страницы по-умолчанию была открыта ветка "Broccoli". Все остальные ветки должны быть закрытыми.

Comment: если тебе нужно решение в лоб - то `this.treeControl.dataNodes = this.dataSource.data; this.treeControl.expand(TREE_DATA[1]); this.treeControl.expand(TREE_DATA[1].children[0]);`. =) И делать это нужно в `ngAfterViewInit`. Т.е. сначала нужно развернуть родительские узлы, а только потом дочерние. Если без хардкода индексов то просто напиши цикл, который соберет тебе нужны узлы в один массив (без вложенности) и дальше просто вызывай `expand(...)` для всех узлов. Например чтоб сигнатура массива была `[ parent, child, grandChild ]`

Comment: "Если без хардкода индексов то просто напиши цикл, который соберет тебе нужны узлы в один массив (без вложенности) и дальше просто вызывай expand(...) для всех узлов. Например чтоб сигнатура массива была [ parent, child, grandChild ]" - Не совсем понял можешь написать пример? Спасибо

Comment: я не могу в комментариях писать код. Тот код выше, что я тебе скинул - рабочий (проверил в твоем же стекблице). У тебя древовидная структура данных, и ты хочешь, чтоб по дефолту были открыты узлы до "Broccoli", то есть тебе нужно обойти это дерево и добраться до узла "Broccoli", при этом тебе нужно знать и родительские узлы тоже (чтобы вызвать expand). Поэтому тебе нужно добраться до узла "Broccoli", а также найти всех его родителей по дереву. В твоем случае `[ parent, child, grandChild ]` - это `[ Vegetables, Green ]` и тебе нужно вызвать expand для этих узлов